# Android: How to get the Checked items of checkbox in RecyclerView to send it to server

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

I am trying to select the checked items of the `checkbox` get the positions of item checked so as to send it to the server.

My adapter is:

```
public class FollowTopicsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FollowTopicsAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {

    ArrayList<String> topics_title, topics_id;
    ArrayList<String> checked_items= new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    public FollowTopicsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> topics_title, ArrayList<String> topics_id){
        this.topics_title=topics_title;
        this.context=context;
        this.topics_id=topics_id;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_for_follow_topics,parent,false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.checkBox.setText(topics_title.get(position));
        holder.checkBox.setTag(topics_title.get(position));

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b)
                {
                    checked_items.add(position,topics_id.get(position));
                    holder.checkBox.setChecked(b);
                    linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checked);
                }
                else
                {
                    checked_items.remove(position);
                    holder.checkBox.setChecked(b);
                    linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_checkbox);
                }

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return topics_title.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkBox;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            linearLayout=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
            checkBox= (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: when an item is checked,you do not need to add item at particular position. you should simply add that topic id if checked else remove that topic id.
and this list contains the topics checked.

Comment: @Egor : My question is that i am not able to click on the item of recycler view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

and yes i got the answer:

```
public class AdapterForFollowTopics extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<String> topics_title, topics_id;
    ArrayList<String> checked_items= new ArrayList<>();
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    ArrayList<String> lstChk= new ArrayList<>();

    public AdapterForFollowTopics(Context context, ArrayList<String> topics_title, ArrayList<String> topics_id){
        this.context = context;
        this.topics_title = topics_title;
        this.topics_id= topics_id;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return topics_title.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return topics_title.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        CheckBox check;
        LinearLayout lv;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        final View rowView;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_for_follow_topics, null);
        holder.check = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        holder.lv = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        holder.check.setText(topics_title.get(position));
        rowView.setTag(holder);

        if(lstChk.contains(topics_title.get(position)))
        {
            holder.check.setChecked(true);
        }

        holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(compoundButton.isChecked())
                {
                    compoundButton.setChecked(true);
                    lstChk.add(topics_title.get(position));
                    holder.lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checked);

                }
                else
                {
                    compoundButton.setChecked(false);
                    lstChk.remove(topics_title.get(position));
                    holder.lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_checkbox);
                }
            }
        });

        return rowView;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see my code here

> https://github.com/masaliev/android-dynamic-table

. I hope you will understand how it is done.

Comment: Thank you Hamza !!

Comment: I'm glad you liked it.